# In Flask, is it possible to make a zip file on the fly and send it to the user?

Tags: python, flask

Using Flask, I'd like to make a button that, when the user clicks it, triggers backend functions that zip the contents of `/some-directory`, send it to the user, then deletes the zip from the server side.

How would I do this with Flask?

Comment: If you know, how to send files and how to create a `zip` archive, you pretty much know everything you need.

Comment: You actually do not need to construct the zip *file* itself. You can simply send the zip stream directly.